# Unable to get Masonry working with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) loaded into my app using RequireJS, but it keeps causing backbone to  spit out a "object is not a function" error anytime I add it.

**Edit**: possibly related to [this issue](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/296).

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.9.1',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore-1.5.2',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone-1.0.0',
    masonry: 'lib/masonry.pkgd'
  },
  shim: {
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }
});

require(['app'], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'masonry',
  'collections/ideas',
], function($, _, Backbone, Masonry, IdeasCollection) {

  var IdeasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#container'),
    initialize: function() {
    ...    
    },
    render: function(){
    ...
    }
  });

  return IdeasView;
});
```

Comment: You need to include more detail.  Can you use the debugger and provide a line number within Backbone where this error is generated?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function backbone-1.0.0.js:908, which is where I believe backbone is parsing the collection fetch results into an array of collection models. Hopefully that is helpful. When I remove the Masonry requirement, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can run it without bridget:

requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "lib-masonry": "Module/js/lib/masonry.pkgd.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "lib-masonry": {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery/ui']
        }
    }
}
```

and then in another module where you want to use it:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'lib-masonry'
], function ($, Masonry) {
    $.widget('ModuleNamespace.containerMasonry', {
        options: {

        },
        _create: function() {
            var msnry = new Masonry('.grid', {
              itemSelector: '.grid__item',
              columnWidth: 200
            });
            // .. code
        }
    });

    return $.ModuleNamespace.containerMasonry;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To use Masonry as a jQuery plugin with RequireJS, you’ll need to run jQuery bridget.

Check the documentation:
http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#requirejs

You can download bridget here:
https://github.com/desandro/jquery-bridget

Then you can include an run bridget and it should work fine

```
define([
    'jquery'
    , 'underscore'
    , 'backbone'
    , 'config'
    , 'app'
    , 'jquery.masonry'
    , 'jquery.bridget'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Config, App, Masonry, bridget) {

   initialize : function () {

        bridget('masonry', Masonry);

   }

});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this saved my day! 
I lost 4 hours on debugging **Magento 2** vs. **Masonry**,
Problem is resolved with **jquery.bridget**